# Applying for f2 visa in last semester

Tags: usa, immigration, student-visa, dependent-visa

I got married 2 months ago and I want to have my wife over. The problem is my current i20 says that my program will end in 2022. However once I apply for my opt, my i20 will say that my program ends in May 2020.

I have two options. Either I apply for F2 visa with my current i20 and then apply for opt. In this case can there be a problem when my wife tries to enter USA using her updated i20 (which will say that program ends in May 2020) while her visa will expire at a later time. Will this difference create an issue at the time of entry?

The second option is that I can wait to get my EAD card and then apply for F2. However, what are my chances to get F2 Visa approved during OPT?

Answer (score 2):

There should not be a problem to apply for an F2 in either situation. A F1/F2 visa gives you the "key" to enter the US. Once inside what matters is your status, which is tied to your i-20. So its fine if the visa does not match the i-20 as long as both expiration dates are in the future.

Furthermore, although your i-20 will say that the program ends on May 2020, the DSO from your school will add a note to the i-20 saying that you applied for the OPT which will extend your status for the duration of your OPT.

Finally, I recommend talking to the DSO about this situation and making a plan together. DSOs also have a point of contact at the DHS in which they can ask questions for unusual situations like yours.